# How to configure the redirect to OpenAM IDP with Spring Security SAML 2.0 without discovery?

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml, openam, idp

I have created the circle of trust between the service provider and the openam IDP. The issue that we are facing is that I am always redirected at the select provider interface. What we want is that the user is been redirected directly for login and authenication to the IDP.

Here is the example used:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/2.0.0.M11/samples/boot/simple-service-provider/src/main/java/sample/config

Based on this I am redirected to the IDP select page, and I want to get redirected to the IDP login page for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one IdP in the list for `bean id="metadata"` this IdP will be used.

Comment: We don't have separeted bean. The configuration is loaded from an yml file from the providers